# Is there a way to restrict which functions could be called through google.script.run?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, web-applications

I just deployed my first google apps script web app. However, I'm concerned about all the functions defined in the code.gs. They could be called by anyone with access to the dev console in chrome. They could call google.script.run on any of them.

Some of those functions are there only as a foundation to use in other functions (example below). Is there a way to restrict which functions could be called through google.script.run?

```
function openRentManagerDatabase (spreaSheetId) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.openByIspreadsheetId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

add `_`after function name, that way it will become a private function and will become inaccessible for `google.script.run`.

It will look like this:-

```
function openRentManagerDatabase_(spreaSheetId) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.openByIspreadsheetId);
}
```

Do note that making it private means you can't run it directly from appscript editor by selecting it.

So  when you want to run it  by calling it through another function, you have to use `_` everytime, just like this `openRentManagerDatabase_()`.

**Reference:**

[Private functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I missed that in their documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions

Comment: Welcome, If you find it useful, you can mark it as accepted answer to make it reference for future sailors :)

Comment: In my scenario, I want to access the function from a javascript file. can you please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/76413040/19021757