# How to hide Google App Script function in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on, custom-function

In the Google **app script project**, I created one function for getting a **token**. It's working fine perfectly in the project. but I **noticed** that my **functions** are **visible** in **Google Sheets**. And it's **returning** the **token** in the **Google sheet cell**. I had attached the image for that.

**-->** You can see that I had defined the **getTokenFromMacro function** for getting **token**.

[image: Function Image]

**-->** Here you can see that my **functions** are **visible** in the **google sheet cell**.

[image: Token in Google Sheet Cell]

So how can I **hide** my token not to **visible** to others or how can I **hide** my **function** to not to be visible in **Google Sheets function**?

I used my **getTokenFromMacro** in a **javascript.html** file.
[image: Used in JS file]

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Google Apps Script allows you to specify if the function is private or if it will be accessible via Google Sheets:

> The name of a custom function cannot end with an underscore (_), which denotes a private function in Apps Script.

You can change your function declaration to:

```js
function getTokenFromMacro_() {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const token = scriptProperties.getProperty('API_TOKEN')
  return token;
}
```

The error `Unknown function: 'getTokenFromMacro_'.` will appear when trying to use it as a custom function:

[image]

---

#### Reference:

- Guidelines for custom functions - [Naming](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#naming)

Comment: I used that function in my javascript.html file. When I'm going to call the getTokenFromMacro_()  function from a javascript file. At that time it's giving an error that google.script.run.withFailureHandler(...).withSuccessHandler(...).withUserObject(...).getTokenFromMacro_ is not a function. I'm not able to access this function in the javascript file. I had attached the image of the js file.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it: from HTML you'll call a public function - nameYouWant() - and that fucntion will call a private function - getTokenFromMacro_()

in GAS

```
function nameYouWant(){
 return getTokenFromMacro_()
}
```

in HTML

```
google.script.run
 .withFailure...
 .withSuccess...
 .withUser...
 .nameYouWant()
```